# Varnish configuration

Tags: magento, nginx, varnish

I'm trying to configure Varnish for my Magento shop. I'm stuck at the configuration:

I already changed

> /etc/default/varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
-T localhost:6082 \
-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
-S /etc/varnish/secret \
-s malloc,256m"
```

TO

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
-T localhost:6082 \
-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
-S /etc/varnish/secret \
-s malloc,1024m"
```

AFAIK I now have to change the nginx.conf but my

> etc/nginx/conf.d

has only these files: "git.conf  nginx_status.conf  ssl.conf  subversion.conf  svndeavdmin.conf  zz010_psa_nginx.conf"

There is an nginx.conf in

> etc/nginx

but I'm not sure if this is the correct file and if yes, what I have to put in there.

I also do not have

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Maybe I could create this folder and put a file in there?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on your questions - you are using Plesk (and it won't work with it) and won't be able to advance further any time soon. Haven't tried to use professional engineer help? :)